# Dapper : reading into dictionary from readrer

Tags: c#, dapper

my reader reads the contents from the stored procedure 
which has one of its 1st select statement as

```
 select id , name from FSubsystem
```

out of 10 select staments

and i declared the dictionary like below
Dictionary SubsystemMApping = new Dictionary();

```
var reader = connection.QueryMultiple(...);
```

I need to read the fist select statement values to dictionary  SubsystemMApping .
 id  - to Key  and 
 name - to value

I tried doing it using reader.Read.Todictionary()  but couldn't succeed . I am not very familier with Func & Action . dats the reason why i think i am not able to understand the 2 overloads of Todictionary properly.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imagine you have a POCO that's returned to you. Something like

```
public class Item 
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

Now imagine you have an `IEnumerable<Item>` and the collection is populated (this is most likely what Dapper is returning).

To use the `ToDictionary` method, you have 2 important overloads.

```
var dictionary = itemList.ToDictionary( item => item.Id );
```

This returns a `Dictionary<int,Item>`. The key for the dictionary is each `item.Id` property.

The key/value overload:

```
var dictionary = itemList.ToDictionary( item => item.Id , item => item.Name );
```

This overload creates a `Dictionary<int,string>` using the specified `item.Id` for key and `item.Name` for value.

There are 2 more overloads that allow you to pass a custom comparer to be used when determining keys.

Comment: I would add the recommendation to use `buffered: false` so that you don't need to iterate the result set multiple times when `ToDictionary` is invoked.

Answer (score 10):

For the generic API, Stan has already described it. The non-generic Read API means you can also bypass the POCO via dynamic:

```
var lookup = reader.Read().ToDictionary(x => (int)x.id, x => (string)x.name);
```

Basically, via "dynamic" it re-exposes the columns as virtual properties.

Comment: for those wondering `reader` in this case is part of Dapper, not `DataReader`. Thanks Mark, now i'm going back to reading your blog.

Comment: @Stan indeed, the `reader` is taken from the question, via `QueryMultiple`

Comment: just wanted to clear it up for anyone who might've missed that.

Comment: I would add the recommendation to use `buffered: false` so that you don't need to iterate the result set multiple times when `ToDictionary` is invoked.